# Create x instances of a class and store the order they were created in

Tags: python, class, variables

I want to create *x* amount of instances of a class and store (inside the instance) the order they were created in. Is there a way that I can do that?

```py
MaxAnts = 100
    
class Ant:
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id
        # then I will use the id to do math

i = 0
if i <= MaxAnts:
    i += 1
    i = Ant(i)
```

But for some reason this doesn't work.

Comment: The reason what you're trying isn't working is that you aren't storing the ants anywhere. 
 `ants = [Ant(i) for i in range(MaxAnts)]` will give you a list called `ants` that contains  `MaxAnts` ants, each with a different `id`.

Comment: You add 1 to *i* then immediately assign *Ant(i)* to the same variable. What were you hoping would happen?

Comment: @Samwise the thing i dont want to store the ants anywhere i just want to create them and then set their id(or the order they spawned in/self.id) and then with this id i can do math inside the ant

im not sure what you're trying to explain to me sorry i dont quite understand (i'm not english i'm french but i posted in english because there is more people in english )
Could you please explain me again ?

Comment: If that's the case just change `i = Ant(i)` to `Ant(i)`.  That will create an `Ant` that is not stored anywhere, and will hence cease to exist.  (I can almost guarantee this is not actually what you want -- you can'd do math with your `Ant` if you can't access it!)  Storing it under the name `i` just breaks your loop because you need that numeric `i` value to keep track of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The class itself can give ids to its instances.

```
class Ant:
    counter = 0  # counter is a class variable

    def __init__(self):
        cls = type(self)
        self.id = cls.counter  # id is an instance variable
        cls.counter += 1

# example:
a = Ant()
b = Ant()
c = Ant()
print(a.id, b.id, c.id) # prints: 0 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension as described in the comments is not a bad way to go but I'll put this here just to give you a introduction to lists.

```
MaxAnts = 100

class Ant:
  def __init__(self,id):
  self.id = id
  #then i will use the id to do math

ants = [] # or ants = list() , same thing
i = 0
if i <= MaxAnts:
  i += 1
  ants.append(Ant(i))
```

The only wierd thing here is that because lists are 0 indexed `ants[0].id` will be 1 and `ant[99].id` will be 100. If you do `ants = [Ant(i) for i in range(MaxAnts)]` you will have your index lined up with your ids, `ants[7].id = 7`. But you could get the same effect by putting `i+=1` after `ants.append(Ant(i))` instead of the line before.

Comment: Other collections in vanilla python include `dict`, `set`, `tuple`. Which all have good docs here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/

Answer (score 0):

To create x amount of instances of some class you would need to use some form of iteration and append them to a collection that you would be able to access.

```py
MaxAnts = 100

class Ant:
  def __init__(self,id):
  self.id = id
  #then i will use the id to do math

ants = []  # A list to store your ants 
for i in range(MaxAnts):  # Iterating i from 0 to MaxAnts - 1
    ant = Ant(i)  # Creating your new ant with the i as a parameter
    ants.append(ant)  # Adding your new ant to the ants list
```

Since by default 'range' gives you a range from 0 to argument - 1, in case you want to start your order from 1, you should start your iteration from 1, and end it on MaxAnts:

```py
for i in range(1, MaxAnts + 1):  # Iterating i from 1 to MaxAnts
```

More on lists: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

More on range: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range